# AngularJS UI Router data persists when navigating from grand-child to parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, javascript-framework

I am having weird issue probably caching issue while navigating from grand-child(`/dashboard/1/production`) to parent(`/dashboard`).

Following are few screenshots:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The selections i.e `Delphi-UI` and `production` shouldn't persists.

Following is my snippet of `application config`:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('root', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
     'header': {
        templateUrl: 'ngapp/templates/header.html'
      }
    }
  })
  // dashboard routes
  .state('root.dashboard', {
    url: 'dashboard',
    views: {
      'content@' : {
        templateUrl: 'ngapp/home/templates/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('root.dashboard.app', {
    url: '/{id:int}',
    views: {
      'body@root.dashboard' : {
        templateUrl: 'ngapp/home/templates/dashboard-body.html',
        controller: 'DashboardBodyCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
  .state('root.dashboard.app.env', {
    url: '/:name',
    views: {
      'body@root.dashboard' : {
        templateUrl: 'ngapp/home/templates/env-content.html',
        controller: 'EnvContentCtrl'
      }
    }
  });
```

And `DashboardCtrl` is:

```
controllers.controller('DashboardCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$timeout', 'appsFactory', function($scope, $http, $state, $timeout, appsFactory) {

  $scope.envs = [];
  $scope.deps = [];      
  $scope.envBtnText  = $scope.appBtnText = "Choose here";
  $scope.headerTitle = "Environment Configuration And Management";
  $scope.appStatus = {
    isopen: false
  };
  $scope.envStatus = {
    isopen: false
  };

  appsFactory.list(function(data) {
    $scope.apps = data;
  });
}]);
```

Full controller code : http://goo.gl/BWtiU5

Project hosted here : https://github.com/budhrg/atlantis-dashboard

Also, navigating back to `Atlantis UI(dashboard)` doesn't reset data like

`$scope.envs`, `$scope.deps`, `$scope.envBtnText` and `$scope.appBtnText`.

What might be issue here? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

> Nested States & Views
>
> When the application is in a particular state—when a state is "active"—all of its ancestor states are implicitly active as well. Below, when the "contacts.list" state is active, the "contacts" state is implicitly active as well, because it's the parent state to "contacts.list".

Your controller isn't getting re-instantiated (expected). There are a couple ways to handle this.

See:

- [How to make angular ui-router's parent state always execute controller code when state changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423962/how-to-make-angular-ui-routers-parent-state-always-execute-controller-code-when)