# How can I reload the same page twice when I click 'ui-sref' by angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I'm using angular-ui-router to manage router of my webapp, 
here got a question...

How can I do reload when I click the same link,
currently when I click a link twice that just load one time...

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? Share some code that you have that is relevant to the question.

Comment: is [`$state.reload()`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) is what you are looking for? Scroll to the `reload` method in the documentation and see whether it's what you need

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24458344/1414641

Comment: Reloading is probably not what you want to do. It is considered bad practice and there is probably a better way to achieve your desired result. Please post some more details about your problem to get a better answer.

Comment: Please have a look at the following link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21714655/reloading-current-state-refresh-data/29384813#29384813 . This is what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the cleaner approach would be the following :

```
<a data-ui-sref="awesomeStateName" data-ui-sref-opts="{reload: true}">Details State</a>
```

We can reload the state from the HTML only.

Comment: so do I need to add something like: params: {reload: false} into stateProvider of this relative router?

Comment: You just need to use 'data-ui-sref-opts="{reload:true}" in your anchor link. This directive is provided by the ui-router itself where you can actually reload the state on click of this particular anchor link.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It's working! BTW what different bewteen 'ui-sref' and 'data-ui-sref'

Comment: since ui-sref, ng-app or any other directive are not HTML5 compatible. So to make it HTML5 compatible we prefix 'data-' before all the angular directives. It is considered to be a good practice. And HTML5 compilers does't throw warnings. Hope that answers your query.

Comment: I see!Thank you every much!